# The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas

**Dataset**

df['sales']

| abd | sales |
| --- | --- |
| atf | 1.2 |
| adstys | 0.9 |
| tyugug | 5.6 |
| gfygv | 1.1 |

**I want to create a new column based on sales values. If sales value is above 1.2 it should replace with 1 or 0 if anything less than 1.2**

Applying list comprehension on a float column is throwing truth value error

```
df['new_sales_index']=df['sales'].apply(lambda x: [1 if y > 1.2 else 0])
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete df?

Comment: condition = df['sales'].astype("float32") >  1.2   \n
df.loc[condition,'sales'] = 0 \n 
df.loc[~condition,'sales'] = 1 \n